# SwiftNIO: Sent package partially received

Tags: swift, bytebuffer, swift-nio

I have developed a client and a server using swift nio, I have no problems sending package of all size between 12 and 1000bytes since server sends a pack of 528bytes and when client got it, it is 512bytes. I'm trying to figure out why it happens. Does anyone knows if there is any chance to set a minimum ByteBuffer capacity? or if I'm missing something.
Thanks to all.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using TCP (that is, using `ClientBootstrap`), you cannot expect that the boundaries of messages sent by the server will be reflected in your reads. TCP is "stream-oriented": this means that the messages don't have boundaries at all, they behave just like a stream of data. In the NIO case, that means you would expect to see *another* read shortly after that contains more data.

The initial `ByteBuffer` capacity used for reads is controlled by the `RecvByteBufferAllocator` used by the `Channel`. This can be overridden:

```
ClientBootstrap(group: group)
    .channelOption(ChannelOptions.recvAllocator, 
                   AdaptiveRecvByteBufferAllocator(minimum: 1024, initial: 1024, maximum: 65536))
```

The standard defaults for the `AdaptiveRecvByteBufferAllocator` in NIO 2.23.0 are a minimum size of 64 bytes, an initial size of 1024 bytes, and a maximum size of 65536 bytes. In general we don't recommend overriding these defaults unless you need to: for TCP NIO will ensure the buffer is appropriately sized for the reads we're seeing.

Comment: Really grateful for the answer. On first developing I started without using NIO and managing server and client with simple tcp network, to pass problem of maximum tcp package size I used to divide them. So on NIO I could imagine it was something like this but I couldn't find anything online to set bootstrap ByteBuffer size.

Comment: If you want to use TCP, you can use length-prefixed framing to delimit your messages. NIO ships some useful helpers: https://github.com/apple/swift-nio-extras/blob/main/Sources/NIOExtras/LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.swift, https://github.com/apple/swift-nio-extras/blob/main/Sources/NIOExtras/LengthFieldPrepender.swift